# Xubuntu dunst high RSS

Tags: xubuntu, ram

I noticed my computer was being slower than normal so I checked the task manager and sorted by RSS usage, and `dunst` is using the most with 1285 MiB. That's a lot for my system, as I only have 3823 MiB of RAM.

I'm not entirely sure what dunst is. Is it necessary or useful? For the time being I've just done

```
killall dunst
```

but I'm not sure how that'll effect my system.

If I'm missing any information please let me know and I'd be happy to look for it.

[image: My system's "screenfetch"]

Answer (score 1):

From `man dunst` "dunst - A customizable and lightweight notification-daemon."

Unfortunately, it suffers from very poor memory leaking. [A quick google search brings up several results with this issue](https://www.google.com/#q=dunst+ram+usage)

Are you using spotify? That is a very quick way for Dunst to rack up RAM usage as every time the song changes you get a notification which stays in memory forever(until dunst is killed).

I haven't found a fix, short of removing dunst, so your best bet is to run `top` then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> to sort by memory usage.

[image: Dunst]

Dunst should be at the top or near the top. Look to the left column to get the PID in this case, 10078.

then kill the dunst pid in this case:

```
kill 10078
```

In my case, RAM usage was reduced by 22% doing that. However, Dunst will just consume more memory as you keep using your PC so you will have to do this often until Dunst is updated.

As for your question "Is it necessary or useful?" it isn't necessary; depending on your programs it can be useful. Personally it only takes about ~15 seconds to kill it every hour or so of listening to spotify so I don't uninstall it, but if you do nothing will be lost. You can remove it with

```
sudo apt-get purge dunst
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Especially when it's a *tall* terminal.

Comment: @muru sorry, was trying to show what top would look like. Edited in a cropped photo.

Comment: When you're already in top, you can press `k`, the `top` command to kill a process, and the default PID is the top PID. Easier than copying/remembering the PID and separately running `kill`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've since upgraded to Xubuntu 16.04 and it doesn't use `dunst`.